# Encoding when requesting a page, python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download a site(with polish signs e.g. "ą ę ć") and save it in a .txt file but whenever I try to print out the content i get weird signs like \xef\xbb etc. I'm using Python 3.4.3 and Windows 7

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = requests.get(url);
site.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.text)
print (soup.prettify())
```

Comment: are you sure the page is utf-8 encoded?

Comment: Setting the encoding attribute overrides the guess requests made about the source encoding, -- it will be used to *decode* `.content` to `.text`.

Comment: Without the site.encoding = 'utf-8' I get the following error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xef' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @user3142434 what line do you get that on, the line of the print statement?

Comment: What does `print(repr(site.content[:3]))` display?

Comment: That's the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) -- try `site.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'`

Comment: Still, the prin (soup.prettify()) gives me the following error:     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2265' in position 7630: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @user3142434 thats a better error, and unfortunately on windows there's not much you can do about it using the command prompt.  The command prompt doesn't handle UTF-8 well at all.  (There are various hacks and workarounds, but none are stable or fully functional).  You could write the data to a file and open in a capable text editor (e.g. Notepad++).  Alternatively, Python's IDLE interactive interpreter handles UTF-8 as do the console of most IDEs (e.g. Eclipse).

Comment: But I've just checked the site encoding and it's utf-8 encoded.

Comment: The encoding you want to force is `utf-8-sig`, which will decode the bytes as UTF-8 as well as strip the UTF-8 BOM `b\xEF\xBB\xBF` -- the issue now isn't decoding the site -- you've done that correctly by using `utf-8-sig` -- the issue is python trying to ***encode*** the UTF-8 string into something command prompt understands -- and it can't, Windows Command Prompt can't handle UTF-8 encoded output.  So you could (instead of `print(soup.prettify())`) write `soup.prettify()` to a file, or use a UTF-8 capable console (Windows Command Prompt is not).